# VBA writing code for standard deviation and Range

Tags: excel, vba, standard-deviation

I am trying to write a function in VBA that will calculate the standard deviation and range of three numbers.  If all of the numbers are determined to be --- then the funtion should output --- as the answer.  If ALL THREE of them are not --- then the standard deviation or range should be calculated with the remaining number while IGNORING the --- number.  The numbers are inputted by the user.  Here is the code I have written for the range and standard deviation calculation.  By using the built in excel WS function which already ignores inputs if they are not numbers I was able to bypass that tricky bit.  However as is visible I have been unable to get the code to recognize when all three are --- to register as ---.

FUNCTION TO CALCULATE RANGE -------------------------------

Function Range(ParamArray ObservedValues())

While ObservedValues(i) = "---"
    Range = "---"
Wend

```
    Max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ObservedValues)
    Min = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(ObservedValues)

    Range = Max - Min
```

End Function

---

FUNCTIONS TO CALCULATE STANDARD DEVIATION (multiple attempts)

**FIRST ATTEMPT**

Function SD(ObservedValueA, ObservedValueB, ObservedValueC, ObservedMean)

If ObservedValueA = "---" And ObservedValueB = "---" And ObservedValueC = "---" Then
    SD = "---"
End If

```
If ObservedValueA <> "---" Then
    a = 1
    x = ObservedValueA - ObservedMean
        Else
        a = 0
        x = 1
End If

If ObservedValueB <> "---" Then
    b = 1
    y = ObservedValueB - ObservedMean
        Else
        b = 0
        y = 1
End If

If ObservedValueC <> "---" Then
    c = 1
    Z = ObservedValueC - ObservedMean
        Else
        c = 0
        Z = 1
End If
```

SD = Sqr((1 / (a + b + c)) * x ^ 2 * y ^ 2 * Z ^ 2)

End Function

**SECOND ATTEMPT**

Function SD(ParamArray Number_Input())

While Number_Input = "---"
    SD = "---"
Wend
            SD = Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev(Number_Input)

End Function

Answer (score 0):

Say your 3 values to compute the sd of are in A1:A3

```
Function sd()
    Dim Val As Variant
    Val = [STDEV.S(IF(NOT(ISNA(A1:A3)),A1:A3))]
    If IsError(Val) Then
        sd = "---"
    Else
        sd = Val
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you edouard for your help.  However this does not completely solve my problem, the numbers that that the user inputs will not always be in sequential order as in A1:A3 often times they will be at random places on the sheet like G4, Y2 and, J17.  This calculation will need to be done numerous times to varying cells.  This is why I wrote my code so that the variables would be determined by the cell selection.